# Android emulator not getting internet

Tags: android

On my emulator , I am not getting internet. But I am able to access google maps. The internet connection is ON. I am using fedora 13 machine . I have checked the default browser in the deice , but then also  am not getting internet. I am getting internet connection on my system. Also i was getting internet connectivity through default browser in the device till yesterday. how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If your system has a internet connection then your emulator also has a connection too, so no need to extra setting for it, (Just check for Airoplanemode disable it display dialog for not internet connection still also Its load the pages).. And also try some URL in android default web browser..

Comment: I am getting internet connection on my system

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the permission listed in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

See the [permissions documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for a complete list of permissions.

Without the permission declared, the sandbox will not let your app access the Internet.

Comment: Here, I'm assuming that your app isn't getting internet access. If the problem is with built-in apps, then this certainly won't help you; but if Google Maps is working, there clearly isn't a complete lack of connectivity on the device.