# Internet Connection issue on emulator,

Tags: android

I am using Emulator to test app.

Problem is Internet on emulator wont work if laptop is connected to LAN. But it works if I connected with Wifi.

I have gone through many answer of similar kind,

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426328/android-emulator-not-getting-internet) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104675/emulator-unable-to-connect-to-internet) but no luck

Comment: You can look at nonanswered questions as a source of info for thinking, but not as examples to put into your code.

Comment: @Marvin i did that,  @ Gangnus, i tried many things,, still same problem, even once my internet stopped working on system too ..:P...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to turn off wifi if using LAN and vice versa. It works, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need android.permission.INTERNET, as it was mentioned. You need also:

ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE - to check if you can use Internet and why not

Maybe CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE

also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206822/no-internet-on-android-emulator-why-and-how-to-fix)

also You can start your AVD in CMD prompt like this

```
C:\program files\android\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator -avd -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

This is google public DNS.
The problem seems to be that the emulator can't find the DNS your computer is currently using. (cite from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376553/upgraded-to-sdk-2-3-now-no-emulators-have-connectivity))

vnshetty managed with: I edited avd with value "GPS support= yes" and restarted the emulator. now working....

more cite: You don't need to set any setting to access internet on emulator unless you are behind a proxy, in case you are behind a proxy start your emulator from command prompt with following command: C:/emulator -avd avdname -http-proxy http://your.proxy.ip:8080 - it seeems to me even more useful .

Comment: I have read about -http-proxy in other posts as well but I don't have one i.e. one with ip and port but I do have a .pac file , how can I use it instead of an ip and port.